# Why am I getting a unrecognized selector sent to instance exception with my MapViewController? (iOS)

Tags: objective-c, ios, unrecognized-selector, cs193p

I'm taking the Stanford iOS class (sorry, I'm one of these guys but gotta learn somehow I guess) and I'm using code that is almost exactly the same as the code that the prof used in the lecture about MKMapViews but I'm getting this exception that he didn't and I really can't figure it out. What could be causing this?

The exception I'm getting:

> -[NSConcreteData _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x90a4c00

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKAnnotationView *aView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"MapVC"];
    if (!aView) {
        aView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"MapVC"];
        aView.canShowCallout=YES;
        aView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
        aView.rightCalloutAccessoryView= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    }
    aView.annotation=annotation;
    [(UIImageView *)aView.leftCalloutAccessoryView setImage:nil];
    return aView;
}

-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    UIImage *image = [self.delegate getImageForMapViewController:self withAnnotation:view.annotation];
    [(UIImageView *)view.leftCalloutAccessoryView setImage:image]; // this is where I get the exception.
}
```

Comment: What is the selector that is not recognized? If you single step, what line of code generates the exception?

Comment: setImage:image in the last line of code

Comment: Post some more detail about your exception... Right now I don't see anything wrong. Unrecognized selector means that you are trying to call a method on an object that doesn't have it.

Comment: Post the full exception data.  The selector name tells you what call was being made.  Most likely the object you think you're calling isn't the one you're calling, either due to a pointer mixup, or because the object was released and the space reallocated to some other object.

Comment: (-1 for not posting the exception data)

Comment: -[NSConcreteData _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x90a4c00

Comment: +1 for "gotta learn somehow I guess" while taking a class at stanford

Comment: In didSelectAnnotationView, after calling getImageForMapViewController, do `NSLog(@"image = %@", image);` and see if it really is a UIImage.

Comment: @JonAird you're overreleasing an object. I guess neither of the answers currently given are quite right.

Comment: @AnnaKarenina I set a breakpoint and the UIImage seems to be fine. Nothing bad would happen if it was nil anyway.

Comment: But did you confirm that it is of type UIImage?  If getImageForMapViewController is mistakenly returning something other than a UIImage, that can cause the error you are seeing.

Comment: @AnnaKarenina Great catch! I was returning NSData on accident. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error `-[NSConcreteData _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` can happen when calling `setImage` on a `UIImageView` if the parameter you are passing is not really a `UIImage`.

According to your comment, the `getImageForMapViewController` method is actually returning `NSData` instead of a `UIImage`.  This can cause the error you are seeing.

Fix the `getImageForMapViewController` method to return a `UIImage`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to change the image of your `MKPinAnnotationView` use like:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    MKAnnotation *pin = view.annotation;
    UIImage *image = [self.delegate getImageForMapViewController:self withAnnotation:view.annotation];

    UIImageView *imagePin = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
   [[mapView viewForAnnotation:pin] addSubview:imagePin];
}
```

Here is the issue, Change this method:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    UIImage *image = [self.delegate getImageForMapViewController:self withAnnotation:view.annotation];
    [(UIImageView *)view.leftCalloutAccessoryView setImage:image]; // this is where I get the exception.
}
```

to

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    UIImage *image = [self.delegate getImageForMapViewController:self withAnnotation:view.annotation];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    view.leftCalloutAccessoryView = imageView; // this is where I get the exception.
}
```

Here the issue is that the `leftCalloutAccessoryView` is of type `UIView`. You are trying to set `image` on `UIView`. `UIView` don't respond to `setImage` method. After setting the image you are trying to cast `UIView` to `UIImageView`, that's a bad habit. So you need to add the image to a imageView after that you need to assign the imageView as the `leftCalloutAccessoryView`.

When you are trying to write like this `[(UIImageView *)view.leftCalloutAccessoryView setImage:image];` remember to cast it first then call the method. For the above line it's better to write like,

```
UIImageView *imgView = (UIImageView *)view.leftCalloutAccessoryView;
[imgView setImage:image];
```

Comment: as long as the annotation can show a callout why does it matter if it's a MKPinAnnotationView or a generic one?

Comment: @JonAird this seems not to be the problem.

Comment: @Midhun MP: All annotation views support leftCalloutAccessoryView which is a view on the _callout_ -- not the image of the annotation itself.